# Lazy loading of images in Magento theme

Tags: image, e-commerce, lazy-loading, magento-1.9

Hye All!

I have a magento ecommerce website.Its taking long time to open because of images. i want to apply lazy loading on magento theme. can anybody tell me how can i do this. i have also tried many jquery plugins but no success.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i tried this extention:  http://www.sessiondigital.de/blog/magento-jquery-lazyload-extension/

Comment: actually i want to load images in magento theme after 3-4 seconds of loading website